# Windows and SQL server keepalive tcp/ip setting

Tags: sql-server, tcp

Perhaps, my question is silly. Anyway, my SQL server has tcp/ip keepalive setting set to 30,000 ms. At the same time, I don't see any registry keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters with regards to keepalive setting.

Hence, I assume that my Windows Server 2008 hosting SQL server is not set up for keepalive tcp/ip feature. Is this correct? If this is correct, does SQL server send keepalive packs to the client?

In other words, does SQL server keepalive feature work if Windows keepalive settings are not set up?

Thank you

Comment: Does anything appear in SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server 2008 Network Configuration ->Protocols -> TCP/IP? I believe the registry is for configuring the entire machine, not necessarily specific 
 SQLServer instances

Comment: Yes. When I mentioned 30,000 ms setting, I meant   SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration ->Protocols for  MSSQLSERVER -> TCP/IP properties Keep Alive configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses the keepalive setting from the registry (2 hrs by default). As LordBaconPants suggested, this works for the entire machine. Separately, SQL Server uses its own keepalive, the one you already saw in SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER -> TCP/IP which has a more appropriate value (for a database server): 30 seconds.

> TCP keepalives for TCP/IP for Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista are disabled by default. If enabled through the use of the setsockopt Windows Sockets function, a keepalive segment is sent every two hours by default, as controlled by the KeepAliveTime registry value. Even if enabled, other upper-layer protocols such as NetBIOS send their own keepalive value. If the keepalive interval that the upper-layer protocol uses is less than the TCP keepalive interval, TCP keepalive value is never sent. For example, NetBIOS sessions over TCP/IP send a NetBIOS keepalive request every 60 minutes. Therefore, TCP keepalive values that are enabled for a NetBIOS session are never used.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd349797(v=ws.10)